# MySQL json_contains_path do not check all objects as expected

Tags: mysql, json

I have images column in database. Which contains array of objects:

```
[
    {
        "disk": "public",
        "name": "IMG_6544.jpg",
        "path": "catalog/76/products/123/GeS4lPBP1qw7fAU1jefshztQZhOiqTwAhn7uEXnu.jpg",
        "type": "jpg"
    },
    {
        "disk": "public",
        "name": "IMG_3900.JPG",
        "path": "catalog/76/products/123/CJeaY22yCkfdkEuH7E2Ibewf1mOElx5vyd7OLy61.jpg",
        "type": "jpg"
    },
    {
        "disk": "public",
        "name": "IMG_6543.jpg",
        "path": "catalog/76/products/123/MH0FGk5NqBlpLFd8Ct06Zb30MfJ4PHfHbG7eYQYc.jpg",
        "type": "jpg",
        "path_mini": "catalog/76/products/123/mini/gFcM6u6mHNBxiMwdzSSNyd9FkyXkARPOuYlpHEgJ.webp",
        "path_webp": "catalog/76/products/123/xw1yhBZ6JTVGGI60opHKlhjjj73srokaxa3Jd3Yg.webp"
    }
]
```

I'm trying to select rows from the `catalog_products` table where the images do not contain the key `'path_mini'`. I'm currently using the following query for this:

```
select *
from catalog_products
where json_length(images) > 0 and json_contains_path(images, 'all', '$[*].path_mini') = 0
```

For some reason, MySQL doesn't detect the JSON in the example I provided. According to the MySQL documentation, this query should check for the `'path_mini'` key in every object of the array. Yet, the query only works correctly when none of the objects contain the `'path_mini'` key.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you need to return only the JSONs with at least one missing key `path_mini`.

One method is to use `JSON_TABLE` to convert array elements into rows then use `group by` and `having` clauses to return those with at least one missing `path_mini` :

```
SELECT images, count(case when path_mini is not null then 1 end)
FROM catalog_products c,
     JSON_TABLE( images, "$[*]"
         COLUMNS(
           path_mini varchar(250) PATH "$.path_mini"
         )
    ) d
group by images
having count(case when path_mini is not null then 1 end) < json_length(images)
```

---

The `json_contains_path(images, 'all', '$[*].path_mini')` will behave same as `json_contains_path(images, 'one', '$[*].path_mini')` since you are passing only one path.

From [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains-path)

> The return value is 0 if no specified path exists within the document.
> Otherwise, the return value depends on the one_or_all argument:
>
> 'one': 1 if at least one path exists within the document, 0 otherwise.
>
> 'all': 1 if all paths exist within the document, 0 otherwise.

So here is how your query may be done, but only if json length is always 3:

```
select *
from catalog_products
where json_length(images) > 0 
      and json_contains_path(images, 'all', '$[0].path_mini', '$[1].path_mini', '$[2].path_mini') = 0
```

Comment: Yes, this method is working, thank you! However, I'm still unsure as to why json_contains_path isn't behaving as I expected in my case. Could you possibly shed some light on this?

Comment: I have added some explanations can you check